# python not reading the entire file

Tags: python, django

I am building a web application which will analyse the apache log file. When I tried to read each line from the log file by using the for loop it skips so many log entries and prints only some of them. I am using python 3.7.2 ,django 2+ and pycharm to build the project

so far i have tried on a access log file from this site https://bureau-ehe.ch/logs/access.log. i have tried with so many other logs also but it also skipping lines.

```
with open('access.log', "r") as f:

    for line in f:
        print(line)

f.close()
```

expected result is to print all the lines but am getting 9 thousand something

Comment: looks fine to me https://repl.it/repls/OurAcrobaticCodewarrior

Comment: You don't need to explicitly `close()` the file when you're using `with`

Comment: how many lines are actually there ? and you are getting 9 thousand and something

Comment: you should not to create many duplicates of the same question, but you need to add details which other people ask you.

Comment: the access log file contain 6146 lines of log entry. am getting 9389 including the blank lines.after each line am getting a blank line

Comment: sorry for creating duplicate questions. but am in a middle of  no where that's made me do so.

Comment: As @JoranBeasley showed, we cannot reproduce your problem: https://repl.it/repls/LimeRawShelfware

Comment: pycharm has a buffer memory for showing the output .. by increasing the memory i solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

print adds a newline by default

```
print(line,end="") # py3
print line,  # py2
```